# How to design GridView with variable size of cell(images) in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, tablelayout

I have to design Gridview with image of different sizes as shown in [This image](http://madept.com/photo.PNG)
IF i choose ListView for design this screen problem is that row has same size.But i want cell in row with different size.Any Suggestion or Sample Code would be appriciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try out this third-party library called StaggeredGridView.

- http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/